# "The term '-Command' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" when trying to execute an inline command in PowerShell Core on Ubuntu

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-18.04, powershell-core

I'm trying to execute an inline command in PowerShell Core (6.2.3) on Ubuntu.

This throws an error:

```
pwsh -Command "Write-Host 'Hello, world'"
```

> -Command : The term '-Command' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I installed PowerShell as a dotnet core global tool if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the command without a parameter name:

```
pwsh "Write-Host 'Hello, world'"
```

[Microsoft's documentation shows that the parameter name is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_pwsh?view=powershell-6), so maybe this is a quirk of installing `pwsh` as a dotnet core tool.